# EXCEL 2010 - Return Highest Value that is NOT a complete number

Tags: excel, lookup

I'm using excel 2010.

I need a formula that will return the highest value of a mixed variable.

Look up VFL will return VFL00151

```
A1 VFL00001
A2 VWS00004
A3 VSC00056
A4 VFL00151
A5 VCC10025
A6 VGH00122
```

I'm avoiding using macros.

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a site where you can post open ended questions asking for solutions without demonstrating some attempt to solve the problem yourself. Please provide details of what you have tried and why it isn't working

Comment: Don't think this can be done without Macros. Unless you split the string using `Left` for the strings into the B column and `Right` into the C column, or use a separate sheet and then use `hlookup` for a drop down menu of each of the B column values.

Comment: Why don't you just use "Text to Columns" command and split the variable in two columns with the fixed column option like shown in the bottom part of [this page](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2027553&seqNum=5). Afterwards you can use an Auto Filter to filter for "VFL" and sort the column with the number from largest to smallest. Is this an option for you? No macro, nor formula... just Excel ;-)

Answer (score -1):

With Col_A referring to your range in column A, and the lookup value (VFL) in C1, the following **array** formula (entered by holding down **ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**, the following formula will perform as you request:

```
=IF(MAX(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,Col_A))))=0,"",INDEX(Col_A,MATCH(MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,Col_A)),--MID(Col_A,4,99),0)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,Col_A)),--MID(Col_A,4,99),0),0)))
```

Of course, this assumes all of your entries start with three letters, and then are followed by digits.

Answer (score -1):

Also, using the same set-up and assumptions as Ron Rosenfeld, but also assuming you're using Excel 2007 or later, **array formula****:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Col_A,C1&"*")=0,"",INDEX(Col_A,MATCH(1,(LEFT(Col_A,3)=C1)*(0+MID(Col_A,4,99)=MAX(IFERROR(0+SUBSTITUTE(Col_A,C1,""),0))),0)))
```

Note also that this solution is case-sensitive whereas Ron Rosenfeld's is not.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The OP posted no attempt to solve the problem - therefore sub-standard.

Answer (score -2):

```
=MAX(--MID(A1:A6,4,LEN(A1:A6)-3))
```

ctrl+shitf+enter when you've entered the formula, to create an array formula. This assumes that all of your numbers have the same form, of 3 letters, then your number.

The mid formula takes the numeric part, based on the pattern you've outlined above. If the pattern is not consistent, you've got less hope with a formula. Doing this as an array, does all of the cells in the range in one step, and returns an array of numbers. This can then be 'maxed'

Update. To take this a step further, and do a lookup on the same principle (without error handling):

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(MAX(--MID(A1:A6,4,LEN(A1:A6)-3)),--MID(A1:A6,4,LEN(A1:A6)-3),0))
```